# SharePoint 2010 Publishing - are you able to modify web part?

Tags: 2010, web-part, publishing-page, publishing

I have a publishing site and I created a page, which allows publishing, but also allows me to add web parts. When I open this page in Designer it informs me that I can only edit the layout mode and not the content..If I want to edit it, I need to use the browser. Is there a way to modify the content? or is the only way I can modify the web part is using css?

This is what it currently looks like:
[image]

What I would like it to look like without the extra title bar or the spacing

[image]

I was able to do this in the non publishing mode of sharepoint 2010...can it also be done in the publishing mode?

Answer (score 0):

once you open it with SharePoint Designer select Advanced mode which allows you to edit the publishing page.

Comment: It allows me to edit the publishing page, but not the web part itself. Thank you.

Comment: did you try to edit it using UI ? like check out the page and edit it.... which may work sometimes

Comment: Yes I did try using the UI, but all I get is the page layout..no content.